# Typescript useState Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I encounter a problem with useState. I try to put a variables initial value into false but the VSCode tells me that it expects 0 arguments on useState function call.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const [isConfirmed, setIsConfirmed] = useState<boolean>(false);
                           Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

Can I get some help?

[VSCode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBjOH.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ekqJ.png)

Comment: You can remove the generic `<boolean>` because you're already defining the initial value as `false` which is inferred as `boolean`. How are you importing the `useState`?

Comment: post your full code, don't just create images

Comment: @nouvist Hello, I have just updated the question:

Comment: Can you post the whole SlideToConfirm.tsx component?